# Regular Expression to match numbers in square brackets in python

Tags: python, regex, text

I need to match and return the string index of numbers which are contained in square brackets. Example string:

> Gabrilovich and Markovitch [11, 12] propose a method to use
>   conditional random fields [6] as a training process.....

Here I would like to extract the index of any given number like 11, 12 or 6 in the above case using regular expressions. I am trying

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[/11/]') # for 11
result =  re.search(pattern, text, flags=0)
print result.start()
```

However with this I am not getting desired results. Note: I would need a solution for matching the exact number I want, not any given number within brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this regex expression `(\[[,\d\s ]*)11([,\d\s ]*\])` for retrieving all the 11's in the text

have a look at the example I uploaded https://regex101.com/r/lN8mA6/1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the regex101 link :)

Answer (score 3):

Since in Python we cannot use variable-width lookbehinds with standard `re` module, you can use capturing groups, and then check the index of the group.

[Sample code](http://goo.gl/qiUrWB) for capturing `11`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\[[^\]]*)\b(11)\b(?=[^\]]*\])') # for 11
text = 'Gabrilovich and Markovitch [11, 12] propose a method to use conditional random fields [6] as a training process.....'
result =  re.search(pattern, text)
if result:
    print result.start(2)
```

Result: `28`.

Note that I am using word boundaries around `11` to only match `11`, and not `111` or `112`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp: `\[\s*(\d*)(\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*)?(\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*)?(\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*)?(\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*)?(\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*)?(\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*)?\]`  (the groups `(\s*,\s*(\d)\s*)?` are repeated to allow to get up to 7 numbers in between the square brackets)  as this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB4bI2/2) shows.  If you want to be more general, you can substitute this regexp with `\[\s*(\d*)(\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*)*\]` that allows an indefinite number of numbers in the list (but then you will get the first and the last only in groups `\1` and `\3`)

If you use the first, you will allow spaces around the commas and you'll get the numbers in groups 1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and 15.